# Redmine - backlogs - No such file to load -- nokogiri

Tags: 12.10, ruby, redmine

I'm trying to install backlogs 0.9.9 plugin for redmine 2.1.2 under ubuntu 12.10.

Following the [Backlogs installation guide](https://github.com/backlogs/redmine_backlogs/wiki/Installation-of-Backlogs-in-Redmine-2.0)

```
remine_install_path$ RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake db:migrate

rake aborted!
No such file to load -- nokogiri
/home/git/redmine/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/acti...
[...]
```

However nokogiri seems to be there

```
$ gem list | grep nokogiri
nokogiri (1.5.5)
```

Am I doing something wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to edit the **Gemfile** and add the below line

```
gem "nokogiri"
```

to solve the dependencies

Source

- http://gembundler.com/man/gemfile.5.html
- http://gembundler.com/gemfile.html

Comment: That fixed my problem, Thanks. I added `gem "nokogiri", ">= 1.4.2"` and reran `bundle install --path vendor/bundle --without test development`. Now I have the same error with `prawn` I imagine I should do the same. Shouldn't there be some commands to set the required dependencies ?

Comment: Actually yes, backlogs should contain the dependencies. I stupidly removed the Gemfile after having conflicting versions. I have put it back by re checking out backlogs

Comment: So putting it back resolved the error with `prawn`?

Comment: Yes, all other errors (apart a conflicting version requirement for `test-unit`) I just commented out one of them